# Why is my C Socket client failing to receive data and it is failing with an error code of 104. Some code is also not being execute

Tags: c, sockets

I have a very big problem that I have encountered with C. I wrote a C client program with a function that is supposed to send and receive data from a server also written in C. But it throws an error. 104. Below is the code for the function.

```
int send_and_receive_data(struct PatientData c, int rcv)
{
    //recv is supposed to determine whether data will be received from the server. it's an integer that can either be 1 or 0 
    if (rcv)
    {
        /*create socket*/
        int network_socket;
        network_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

        //specify an address for the socket
        struct sockaddr_in server_address;
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        int connection_status = connect(network_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
        // check for error with the connection
        if(connection_status == -1){
            printf("There was an error making a connection to the remote socket\n\n");
        }

        //send data to the server
        if(send(network_socket,&c,sizeof(c),0) < 0){
            puts("Send Failed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //puts("Data sent\n");
        }

        if(recv(network_socket,&s_results,sizeof(s_results),0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Receive Failed %d\n",errno);
            printf("Sara Nakamya 2019-01-01 F Mary\n");
        }
        else
        {
            // output the received data
            puts("Receive successful");
            printf("%s %s %s %s\n",s_results.patient_name,s_results.patient_date,s_results.patient_category,s_results.patient_gender);
        }

        // and then close the socket
        close(network_socket);
    }
    else
    {
        /*create socket*/
        int network_socket;
        network_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

        //specify an address for the socket
        struct sockaddr_in server_address;
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        int connection_status = connect(network_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
        // check for error with the connection
        if(connection_status == -1){
            printf("There was an error making a connection to the remote socket\n\n");
        }

        //send data to the server
        if(send(network_socket,&c,sizeof(c),0) < 0){
            puts("Send Failed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Data sent\n");
        }

        // and then close the socket
        close(network_socket);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function sends data to the server and also receives data on the same connection. Now my problem is that the `recv()` function call always fails with an error code of 104 even when the server has sent data back to the client socket.

Below is the code for the server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
/*
Input Data using commands
Send data to the server
The server writes the data to a text file
Database connection in C
*/


struct patient_data
{
    char patient_name[256];
    char patient_date[256];
    char patient_category[256];
    char patient_gender[10];

} s_results;

int main()
{
    // create the server socket
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    // define the server address
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // bind the socket to our specified IP and port
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address,sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket,100);

    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(server_socket,NULL,NULL);    

    struct data
    {
        int type;
        char name[100];
        char date_of_identificaton[20];
        char category[10];
        char gender[5];
    } response;
    // receive data from server 
    recv(client_socket,&response,sizeof(response),0);

    if(response.type == 1)
    {
        puts("Check_status");
        char name[] = "Okello Ivan ELijah";
        char date[] = "2019-01-01";
        char category[] = "Ass";
        char gender[] = "M";
        strcpy(s_results.patient_name,name);
        strcpy(s_results.patient_date,date);
        strcpy(s_results.patient_category,category);
        strcpy(s_results.patient_gender,gender);
        send(server_socket,&s_results,sizeof(s_results),0);
        puts("Data sent\n");
        printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n",response.name,response.type,response.gender);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Data not sent");
    }
    // close the socket
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

The server also does not execute the if statement fully. It just executes the first statement of the `if else` statement and doesn't execute the others. What could be the problem??
Please help me with this anybody

Answer (score 2):

> ... even when the server has sent data back to the client socket.

Actually, your server does not send data to the client. You probably intended it with this line in the server:

> ```
>    send(server_socket,&s_results,sizeof(s_results),0);
> ```

Only, this is using `server_socket` which is the listener socket. Instead it should have used `client_socket`, which is the connected socket. Note that if you would have checked the `send` call for errors you would have realized that the `send` has failed too. Thus, better check for errors on **all** places.

Comment: ....and the client mishandles TCP streaming, as usual, expecting messages,longer than one byte to be received in one recv() call:((

Comment: @MartinJames so I can't receive data longer than 1 byte?? How come on the server I can receive data longer than 1 byte with the same function `recv()`

Comment: hey @SteffenUllrich thanks for the sugggestion but still the problem persists.

Comment: @ElijahOkello no, you cannot guarantee that recv(), if sucessfull, will return more than one byte.  You MUST code so that if there was someone typing slowly at the peer, and so recv() was returning with one char loaded each time, your code will still work correctly.  If you neglect that, your system will be unreliable:(  Sure, while testing on the local stack, you may well get one recv for every send, but that is not a lock:)

Comment: @ElijahOkello: *"...  but still the problem persists ..."* - I have no idea how your code looks right now, if you have added the necessary error checks also to `send` and if you get exactly the same error at exactly the same place. It would be useful if you provide a minimal __but complete__ code so that one could easily reproduce your problem.